# How to merge multiple columns into one variable (which is a list) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, variables, dataframe, merge

I have the following string columns.

```
Str1    Str2    Str3
OK      I       Go
Yes             Hm
Fine    I see
```

I want to combine them into one list variable

```
AllStr
["ok", "I", "Go"]
["Yes", "Hm"]
["Fine", "I see"]
```

I tried different method, I came close but not quite right:

```
df_manual_label['AllStr'] = df_manual_label[['Str1', 'Str2', 'Str3']].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with `stack`

```
df['New']=df.replace('',np.nan).stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list)
df
Out[1666]: 
   Str1   Str2 Str3            New
0    OK      I   Go    [OK, I, Go]
1   Yes          Hm      [Yes, Hm]
2  Fine  I see       [Fine, I see]
```